# Jenkins is not opening in browser only in my laptop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins

From two days I am facing this problem. Till 2 days before Jenkins.... worked without any error in my laptop. My Jenkins server is in AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux). All my deployments are also there in Jenkins.

The problem is …. it is not loading in the browser only in my laptop but when i checked in other's laptop it is working fine.

Also in my lapotp with organization's wifi it is not loading but when i tried with my mobile hotspot jenkins is working. How to solve this ?

How to solve this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Speak to your IT department.
Seems like the common denominator is the company network.
More than likely the connection is being blocked.